# Using $q promises, passing arguments to next function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For promises, is there an accepted method to pass more than one parameter to the next function in a promise chain?

Some background:

I have a project in which we are using promises to handle asynchronous calls to a database. I have a function in a library we are using that's roughly of the form:

```
executeSql(statement, options, successCallback, failCallback)
```

Since this is in a long string of promises, I need to make it also into a promise so I can .then it.

I tried the following:

```
$q(function(resolve, reject) {
    executeSql(statement, options, resolve, reject);
}).then(function(tx, results) {
    alert(tx);
    alert(results);
}
```

The first parameter comes through fine, but the second does not. If I do this:

```
executeSql(statement, options, function(tx, results) {
    alert(tx);
    alert(results);
}, null);
```

everything works as expected.

It seems like a promise only sends a single parameter to the next .then function. Unfortunately, since the first one is the one I don't care about and only one gets sent along, I have no way to access the results.

I have a workaround for this specific issue, but my general question remains.

For reference, the workaround is:

```
$q(function(resolve, reject) {
    executeSql(statement, options, function(tx, results) {
        resolve(results);
    }, reject);
 });
```

But that only works because I only care about passing on the results in this particular case.

Comment: Have you tried sending it an array of parameters and just passing the array?

Comment: You can send it by passing in one array (tx and result in one array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AngularJS $q API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), you can only pass a single parameter to the resolve function.  So to pass multiple variables you'd have to wrap them in an object. I.e. you could call:

```
resolve({'tx':tx, 'results':results})
```

and your then function would look something like:

```
.then(function(wrapperObj) {
  alert(wrapperObj.tx);
  alert(wrapperObj.results);
})
```